# Why my gradle sync always download groovy-xxxx-3.0.9.pom every time?

Tags: android, gradle

This is an android project and I do not have explicit dependency for groovy-xxxx-3.0.9.pom (like datetime \util\ console etc), but the gradle sync will download them every time. My build.gradle.kts also do not use groovy.

How to debug this or disable this ?

Comment: hello, any solution? i hava the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Gradle 7.6?
For me issue started after upgrading to Gradle 7.6
Rolling back to Gradle 7.5.1 fixed the issue.