# Intellij Gradle Sync re-downloads groovy runtime jars every time (groovy-all, groovy-datetime, groovy-util)

Tags: java, windows, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

It appears that the caching is broken on windows for newer versions of gradle and on windows specifically. the [workaround being described in this question is also not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519672/why-my-gradle-sync-always-download-grooy-xxxx-3-0-9-pom-every-time).

Comment: unlike that other question, which suffers seo issues because, e.g. groovy is misspelled, i will edit this question to refine it until a solution is found.

Comment: Could you please share sample project example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @DaveAnkin Questions can be edited by anyone (or at least put in the revision queue).

Comment: with exceptions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84398

Answer (score 0):

one answer i have come across is offline mode, by putting

```
// startParameter.offline = true
```

into your `~/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle`, like so:

```bash
echo '// startParameter.offline = true' > ~/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle
```

i have then developed a couple of shell functions to switch it on and off as the ide struggles or doesn't:

```bash
gradle_online() { sed -i 's/^\(startParameter.offline\)/\/\/ \1/' ~/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle; }
gradle_offline() { sed -i '1s#^// *##' ~/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle; }
```

Comment: That's not really a solution, but at most a work-around. :-D Anyway, the Gradle toolwindow in IJ has a dedicated button for toggling offline mode when used from IJ, so you can just press that instead of using that. Besides that, you should probably report this either to JetBrains or Gradle, including a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i wish i could reproduce reliably :-P the button is also nice, i should probably convert my answer to a community wiki and add it as well. hard to learn these little gems without stackoverflow/community research

Comment: also am beginning to think that this is more of an intellij issue, as this little hack is the only thing which allows me to actually reload changes for new dependencies in intellij. in truth, i blame our slow artifactory instance.